# the derivate over double integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let's consider the function $ f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R $ defined by $ f(t)= \int_0^t \int_0^tg(x,y) \, dx \, dy$. Where $g:[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function.

Compute $f'(t)$ by doing this:

$i)$ First prove that for every fixed $s$ the function $h(y)=\int_0^s g(x,y) \, dx $ is continuous.
I proved this point. I only considered the fact that $g$ is uniformly continuous.

$ii)$ Now consider the function $F:[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by $ F(t,s)= \int_0^t \int_0^sg(x,y) \, dx \, dy$ and use the chains rule to compute the derivate